# Making a class of ID's to work with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have to do a project where i have to run multiple test. I was wondering if there is anyway i can have a class with all of the ID's of the elements. I want to do this because it would be easier to edit one file later on rather than multiple files. Im new to selenium Webdriver do any simple way of doing this? also can you do this with simple task, ex. I want to login to a website on 10 different tests but i dont want to duplicate the code. can i also add this in with the class of id's.

Comment: Read webdriver wiki about page object's